# how do tasks get executed in spark engine ( referred to DAG )?

Tags: apache-spark

I'd be grateful if someone answers me and explained to me this matter.

from what I understand, DAG is the physical plan of how the job will be done, but I didn't understand how does it really do tasks in parallel.
I elaborated my questions and I hope I get answers.

[an example of a DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aipyy.png)

1) how do tasks are divided into stages? ( in low-level speaking )

2) providing a siffusante number of executors, do tasks in one stage work simultaneously?

and if so, does that mean that **number of tasks that run in parallel** equal to the **number tasks in independent stages ** ?

3) lastly, when do the stages work in parallel? how can I know the number of parallel execution stages from the DAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

A general rule of thumb is each stage is a shuffle operation,
shuffle operations are operations that will need to be reduced in the end to one machine (I.E. reduce,join,count)
which means not all tasks can run concurrently ( although the starting tasks can ) and they require moving data across executors . That means this operations are very expensive to the regular transformation operations (I.E. map filter) .

Which is why stages are created according to shuffle operations.

One of the biggest advantages in Spark to mapreduce in terms of speed is once you set up an executor it will usually stay alive for the duration of the job so doing 2 small map operations will Usually be joined together to a single map behind the scenes. The same cant be done with shuffle operations.

So to summarize , each stage contains tasks that can run in parallel .

2.

the number of tasks that will be able to run concurrently is (num executors * num of cores on each executor)

3.

different stages dont run in parallel only tasks

Comment: so do tasks in the same stage work simultaneously? , so what does the line between partitions in the same stage refer to? do the tasks in the same stage are independent?

Comment: They should be yes.